# AngularJS: looping ajax requests, fetch data to scope when done

Tags: angularjs, view, angularjs-scope, factory

In my controller, I'm calling a factory that fetches data from an API, then in the success function, the data is passed to another function that loops through it and calls another factory each round in the loop. The data retrieved from the second factory is then mashed up with the data from the first factory in a new object, each round in the loop, and pushed to an array.

When I add the data to the $scope, the view is being updated as the data is being fetched, you can see that the items in the view are added one by one and not all in a bunch.

I also need to sort the data in the $scope before it hits the view.

Is there a way to do this when all actions are finished? – When all data is fetched.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, firstFactory, secondFactory) {
    var objArray = [];

    function doStuff() {
        firstFactory.getData().success(function(data) {
            doMore(data);
        });
    }

    function doMore(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            secondFactory.getData(value).success(function(result) {
                var obj = {
                    test: result.test,
                    test2: value.test
                };
                objArray.push(obj);
            });
        });
        $scope.data = objArray;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain promises. A promise in the chain is only run when the previous has executed, or you can even run promises in parallel and with $q.all wait for all promises to finish.

Here is a sample that might help you [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WHiSFiadlkAUGaXEZbhU?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('dataFactory', function($http, $q) {
  var getData = function() {
    var combinedData = [];
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('first.json')
      .then(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        firstData = data;

        $http.get('second.json').then(function(secondData) {
          angular.forEach(firstData.data, function(value, key) {
            combinedData.push(value);
          });

          angular.forEach(secondData.data, function(value, key) {
            combinedData.push(value);
          });

          deferred.resolve(combinedData);
        });
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return {
    getData: getData
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataFactory) {
  $scope.items = [];
  var onSuccess = function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;
  };

  var onError = function() {
    console.log('error');
  };

  dataFactory.getData()
    .then(onSuccess, onError);
});
```

Comment: I've read the documentation but don't quite get it. Could you show how it could be used in my sample code above?

Comment: I edited my answer and provided a plunker sample. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it doesn't work for what I am doing. When I am making the looped calls to the secondFactory, I need to send in parameters from the fetched data from the firstFactory... The result is not two list put together, it's a mashup. like a = {name:'Peter', email:'peter@peter.com'}; b = {company: 'IBM', email: 'peter@peter.com'}; combined = {name: 'Peter', email: 'peter@peter.com', company: 'IBM'};

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, it is difficult to grasp your problem without a concrete sample, i.e. a plunker code sample of your problem would surely help.

Answer (score 0):

For the second call you can use $q.all. This would get resolved only when all the calls are complete

```
function doMore(data) {
    var promises = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        promises.push(secondFactory.getData(value));
    });
    $q.all(promises).then(function (responseArray) {
            $.each(responseArray, function (result) {
                var obj = {
                    test: result.test
                };
                objArray.push(obj);
            });
            $scope.data = objArray;
        });
}
```

Comment: That creates a whole lotta duplicates.

Comment: My bad, made a mistake. Check now.

Comment: It should be "key" as well: $.each(responseArray, function (key, result)... The idea works, but in my real code I still have to access the value in data when building the mashed up object. This way it can't be done since it's outside the original loop. Isn't there a way to use promises inside the factory success function?

Comment: I'll use this approach, but I'll loop through the data from firstFactory a second time to check the values in the responseArray, and then combine the datas from the two factories into one object. It feels not so neat though, having to loop through the same collection twice.